# DateValue("Mar/02/2015") results in type mismatch. Regional settings Germany

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote code to display quarters of a year instead of using exact dates.
It looks like this:

```
"Q" & Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Month(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value) / 3, 0) _
    & " " & Year(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value)
```

`ws.Cells(i, 3).Value` can be `"Mar/06/2015"` and any other date. However `"Feb/06/2015"` works but I get a type mismatch for "`Mar/06/2015"`. Why?

Comment: Your code is trying to coerce text to a date value using your regional settings, which I guess are German. Since March is März, not Marz, in German, the conversion fails. (Februar works). You should either enter convert the data to proper date values, or use the correct three letter abbreviation.

Comment: You are guessing right ;-) Is there a way to force Excel to use English regional settings? Through VBA? I cannot change the cells content as they come from another system. If I use German abbreviations though, I believe a non German user will get an error, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data format is consistent, you can use this function to return an actual date value from the cell, which you can then use your `Month` and `Year` functions on:

```
Function GetDate(sInput As String, Optional sDelimiter As String = "/") As Date
    Dim vParts
    vParts = Split(sInput, sDelimiter)
    GetDate = Evaluate("DateValue(""" & vParts(1) & "-" & vParts(0) & "-" & vParts(2) & """)")
End Function
```

Comment: It rearranges the date string into a US format (so `Mar/06/2015` becomes `06-Mar-2015` for example) and then uses Evaluate so that DateValue will work using US settings rather than whatever regional settings the user has.